# Ajax form data reaching .done(function (data)) but no data posted to db

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am having some issues with information posting to my database. I have other information posting to my database via ajax call in my javascript and it posts no problem, however, I don't know what is wrong with this part of my code. It refuses to post to the database. I wanted to post it and see if anyone spots something that I don't that would prohibit it from making it to the database. The funny thing is, the ajax call is  making it inside my `.done function(data)` for my ajax call, but nothing is going into my database.

Below I have posted all code that I believe is relevant

```js
$('#form-reg').on('submit', function(){
      // serialize the form
      var formData = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
          type        : 'POST',
          url         : 'register.php',
          data        : formData,
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data),
         },
         error: function(err){ console.log(err)
         };
      })
      .done(function (data) {
           console.log("lo");
            document.getElementById('form-reg').reset(function(){
                alert("signed  up completed");
          });
      })
      .fail(function (error) {
          alert("POST failed");
      });
      return false;
  });
```

```css
/*mysqli_connect.php -- note this is just an old file name. not important*/
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = '';
$password = '';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>

/*register.php*/
<?php
require 'mysqli_connect.php';
if((isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']))||
   (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']))){

  $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO test_table (comment) VALUES(?,?);');
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $sth->execute(Array($name, $email));

}
else{
  echo 'error no comment entered';
}
?>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">

<div id = "register-container">
    <form id = "form-reg">
      <label id ="x" for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name-reg" name="name"></br>
      <label id = "y" for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="email-reg" name="email"></br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id = "submit-reg">
    </form>
  </div>
```

. If I miss something feel free to request that piece of code.

Comment: Add success and error callbacks to the ajax options object. This way you'll know whats happening.

Comment: If you take a look, I have a call back inside my `.done` function and the callback doesn't work already. so not sure if adding another would work. That is a separate issue. I was never able to get that callback inside my `.done` to fire.

Comment: $.ajax({
          type        : 'POST',
          url         : 'register.php',
          data        : formData,
         success: function(data){
                   console.log(data),
                  },
error: function(err){
                   console.log(err),
                  }
      })

Comment: a two printed out in the console with a circle around it? Other than that. Nothing. I think that's just the number of times the my other console log printed.

Comment: Edited the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is in:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (comment) VALUES(?,?);
```

Why is there one col "(comment)" while in VALUES there are two (?,?) placeholders? What columns are in the table "test_table"? I think the query might be something like:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (name, email) VALUES(?,?);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in your PHP.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO test_table (comment) VALUES(?,?);');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Your SQL doesn't know what the question marks (?) are unless you give them a value. Look at the example below:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(?,?);');
$sth->bind_param('ss', $name, $email); // you must bind the values you wish to insert
$sth->execute();
```

For more information about bind_param take a look at the PHP Documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I gave it a whirl, but no luck. I'll be sure to read up on the documentation either way!